# using EVE Python api for request and response

Tags: python, python-3.6, eve

I am trying to use the `EVE api` with `python 3`. This is for the first time I am trying to use the API. So what I am trying to do and achieve is given below:
I have a list of name of people. for example:

```
Adam Gilchrist
Adam Barbar
Adam lobiof
Jaffer Wilson
Janet Wilson
Jane Cold
```

And many others. I am using the `fuzzywuzzy` python library. I have loaded these names into an array and using the library function for predicting the approx match of the string from the names using their email address names. For example:
`adam.barbar@example.com` is the exampe I have taken. Now, I have written the code for match the string `adam.barbar` with the name list that I have mentioned above.
I get the approx answers as expected.
Now where is the problem one might think. So here it is:
I want to fetch the response from the API as:

```
http://127.0.0.1/people/?email=adam.barbar@example.com
```

and get the response as the answer of `fuzzywuzzy` library as json to display on the screen.
I am not using any Database as such and all the names are available in the file format currently.
I have search and research about the usage of the `EVE API`, but could not find the usage as per my requirement. Where ever I searched for the solution I came across MongoDB or any other database. My requirement is database less.
So I want to know in the above mentioned condition, What need to be done if I want to use the `Eve API`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not using any Database as such and all the names are available in the file format currently.

As you are not using a database, you can use plain flask to solve your problem. It can easily return json for any request with the aptly named `jsonify`:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request

def your_normal_code_here(email):
   return something

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/v1.0/people', methods=['GET'])
def people_api():

    email = request.args.get('email')

    if email is None:
       make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Missing email parameter'}), 400)

    return jsonify(your_normal_code_here(email))
```

For more robustness and completeness of your API, try using a lightweight framework like [`flask-restful`](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/).

Comment: I am not looking for the email to be jsonified but the response which I will get after querying the array I have made using the fuzzywuzzy and the email first part. Hence, What I only need to know is how to get request as email address and response as json of the output of fuzzywuzzy program on the browser.

Comment: Replace the body of `your_normal_code_here` with the fuzzywuzzy function, and the rest does exactly what you require

Comment: ok.. let me check it... if it works I will accept your answer as answer...

Comment: I have written code like this:https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/01cd2c5f028992a84a04a6bfe511d50e
I want to know how the request is made and displayed. Can you please add that part. I tried something like this: http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1.0/people/adam@example.com

Comment: `127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1.0/people?email=adam@example.com`

Comment: just one more request. I want to know how I can display the output in Key value format. What I get as output is merely the array of names and the matching percentage. Can you help me labelling the json as `result=['name':'name_of output', 'confidence':'80']` something like this

Comment: This is not json format; so why do you want it like this?

Comment: it will help me in getting proper display for my analysis. As this is the smallest part of my project and there are other outputs coming with it. Hence, need a bifurcation. Thats it and nothing else.